# Running python script on task scheduler removes zip attachment

Tags: python, zip

I can successfully run my python script and send/recieve zip attachments using IDLE however when I run the same script via task scheduler I receive the same email but without the zip file.  Instead there is a text file that says "this attachment was removed".  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is my code used for attaching the zip file

```
#zip up contents

ProjectZFile = "project.zip"

zf = zipfile.ZipFile(ProjectZFile, "w")
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(project):
zf.write(dirname)
for filename in files:
    zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
zf.close()

# attach zip file

fileMsg = email.mime.base.MIMEBase('application',"zip")
fileMsg.set_payload(open(ProjectZFile, "rb").read())
encoders.encode_base64(fileMsg)
fileMsg.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(ProjectZFile))
emailMsg.attach(fileMsg)
```

Comment: Could it be the firewall of the receiver that removes the attachment?

Comment: Your set_payload line should crash if the file does not exist anymore

Comment: Sounds like your email provider removed the attachment. Try manually sending a message with the same attachment to the same email address.

Comment: I sent the email to the same email address and got the same result.  I will try a different SMTP email provider

Comment: I solved the problem.  Task scheduler requires the full directory path name in order to work i.e ProjectZFile = 'C:\\Scripts\\project.zip'